# My onclick successfully makes an ajax call but for some reason doesn't executes the alert(1);

Tags: javascript, jquery

So my ajax call successfully executes and updates my database, however, anything else I include does not work. This alert(1); does not alert anything. Any on click event handle inside doesn't work either and I'm not sure why.

html

```
echo    "<div class='upvoteDownvoteRatingContainer'>
                    <form class='upvoteImage' method='POST' action=''>
                        <input type='hidden' name='action' value='upvote'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='userId' value='".$currentUser."'>
                        <button class='upvoteImageButton' type='submit'><img class='arrowUp' src='../images/Social Media/arrowUp.png' alt='submit'></button>";
echo        "</form>";
```

Javascript

```
$('.arrowUp').onclick(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert(1);
        var form = $(this);

        var id = form.find("input[name='id']");
        var userId = form.find("input[name='userId']");
        var action = form.find("input[name='action']");
        var ratingNumber = form.parent('.upvoteDownvoteRatingContainer').find('.ratingNumber');

        $.post('../includes/voting.inc.php', {id: id.val(), userId: userId.val(), action: action.val()}, function(data){
                ratingNumber.html((data));
        }, 'json'); 
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery, the `.onclick()` function does not exist. You can either do this:

```
$('.arrowUp').on('click', function(){ /* ... */ });
```

or this:

```
$('.arrowUp').click(function(){ /* ... */ });
```

Comment: @PeterAtanasov The ajax is not executed. Your form is actually submitted and your page is refreshed (because your `e.preventDefault()` is not executed)

Comment: Ohhhh, that makes sense. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome :) It's a common mistake. It's always good to open your console (F12) when developing. It will show you errors, and there is a "network" tab which shows the requests that are made.